# Can someone bring his wife to Spain (he is non-EU, and studying for a Master's in Spain)?

Tags: immigration, spain

My friend is from Bangladesh. He is studying for a Master's in Spain. Recently, he went to Bangladesh on vacation, and got married there with a Bangladeshi girl. He is currently in Bangladesh, although he will leave soon. He wants to bring his wife to Spain.

What can he do? What is the procedure?

Comment: anyone please? .....